# Function that to exit from other function

Tags: python-3.x, function

I wanted to create to a function which, when called in other function it exits the previous function based on the first function's input.

```
def function_2(checking):
        if checking == 'cancel':
             # I wanted to exit from the function_1
def function_1():
        the_input = input("Enter the text: ")
        function_2(the_input)
```

I wanted the code for the `function_2` so that it exits from `function_1`, I know that I can put the `if` statement in `function_1` itself but ill use this to check more than one in input in the same function or even in different function I cant put the `if` block everywhere it will look unorganized so i want to create a function and it will be convenient to check for more than one word like if `cancel` is entered i wanted to exit the programm if `hello` is entered i wanted to do something, to do something its ok but to exit from the current function with the help of other function **code please** :) if any doubts ask in the comment ill try to give you more info im using python 3.x.x on Windows8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
def should_continue(checking):
    if checking == 'cancel':
        return False
    return True

def function_1():
    the_input = input("Enter the text: ")
    if not should_continue(the_input):
        return
```

This is the best solution I think.

Another alternative is to raise an Exception, for example:

```
def function_2(checking):
    if checking == 'cancel':
        raise KeyboardInterrupt

def function_1():
    the_input = input("Enter the text: ")
    function_2(the_input)

try:
    function_1()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("cancelled by user")
```

Comment: If I would use your second solution Will the program terminates after the `except` block, I wanted to clarify because I don't want to terminate the program I just wanted to exit the function I wanted the program to continue running if the program terminates then please help by correcting your program such that the program doesn't terminate I don't want to use the first solution because my aim is to eliminate the use of `if` block inside the `function_1`. I'll be using the `function_2` in a few more other functions which will make the program longer and irritating to code. Thank you.

Comment: No, the second solution will not end your program, just try it... And i still advise you the first, because an `if` statement is not irritating: what is irritating is an unreadable program. Take a look there: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/